# How to pass options to tf.Session().run while using Keras Model.fit()?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to pass `options` and `run_metadata` to `tf.Session().run()` while still using `Keras.Model.fit()`?

The only way I see to use those run options is to take control over the TF session from Keras by implementing the training loop myself. But I was I wondering if you know of a way that avoids that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model.compile` takes keyword arguments which are passed to `session.run`.

Comment: Ah, I see it now: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L615-L617. Thank you! I will test it and get and confirm.

Comment: @Mustafa Were you able to pass options? I get `ValueError: ('Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['options']))
`

Comment: Yes, it did work for me back then. I am not sure if the interface has been updated, I doubt it though.